# How can we pass a dictionary from feature file to test file. (pytest-bdd)

Tags: python, pytest, gherkin, python-behave, pytest-bdd

I am trying to pass a dictionary from a feature file to my test file. I searched a lot but couldnt find a way to pass a dictionary.

Below is one example that is available in behave which I wanted to achieve in pytest-bdd
[image: Pass dictionaty from feature file to test]

Reference link:
[How can I pass an object like a list or dictionary in python behave .feature file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635025/how-can-i-pass-an-object-like-a-list-or-dictionary-in-python-behave-feature-fil/52711243#52711243)

Please let me know if someone already have a solution for the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## After giving many tries, now I am able to do this. Below is the script which I tried.
Feature file:

```
  Scenario Outline: Dictionary
    Given Access Dictionary list
      [
        { "abc":"test1","def":"test2"},{ "ghi":"test3","jkl":"test4"}

      ]
```

Test file:

```
@given(parsers.parse('Access Dictionary list\n{table_data:json}', extra_types=dict(json=json.loads)), target_fixture="mytabledata")
def step_setup(table_data):
    global data
    MyTableData = UserList(table_data)
    #print(MyTableData)
    print(MyTableData[1]["ghi"])
```

## Output: test3

HAPPY THAT I AM ABLE TO DO IT ON MY OWN :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share table_data? When I execute the above test class, it throws error

E       fixture 'table_data' not found

> ```
>   available fixtures: _driver, _driverAPI, _driverlaunchgnp, _pytest_bdd_example, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, extra, extras, include_metadata_in_junit_xml, metadata, monkeypatch, pytestbdd_given_Access Dictionary list
>   {table_data:json}, pytestbdd_given_trace, pytestbdd_then_trace, pytestbdd_when_trace, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>   use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
> ```